# warning: [R.swift] project.pbxproj is internally inconsistent

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, r.swift

I have just started working on an older project where there are many Xcode warnings.

One of the warnings is an R.swift warning:
"[R.swift] project.pbxproj is internally inconsistent."

In the Build target - Log it says:
"warning: [R.swift] project.pbxproj is internally inconsistent.

- XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference (FF0493CB254AF9C600793461) is not used
- XCSwiftPackageProductDependency (FF0493CC254AF9C600793461) is not used
- XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference (FF0493D0254AFB0200793461) is not used
- XCSwiftPackageProductDependency (FF0493D1254AFB0200793461) is not used
- XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference (FF0493D5254AFBA700793461) is not used
- XCSwiftPackageProductDependency (FF0493D6254AFBA700793461) is not used
- XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference (FF0493DC254AFC1400793461) is not used
- XCSwiftPackageProductDependency (FF0493DD254AFC1400793461) is not used
- XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference (FF0E61E42555483600A936BA) is not used
- XCSwiftPackageProductDependency (FF0E61E52555483600A936BA) is not used
- XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference (FFB880FF27D7985600230B89) is not used
- XCSwiftPackageProductDependency (FFB8810027D7985600230B89) is not used
- XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference (FFE983FB256BC2590059CB8E) is not used
- XCSwiftPackageProductDependency (FFE983FC256BC2590059CB8E) is not used
- XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference (FFF90DB328BE1D0E003437C7) is not used
- XCSwiftPackageProductDependency (FFF90DB428BE1D0E003437C7) is not used

Perhaps a merge conflict?"

When I look up this kind of error I get to the GitHub repo of R.swift where it seems to be about local vs remote packages, but I must admit that I don't understand the error. And I don't seem to find any fixes for the problem.
Maybe this query is meant to be directed at the R.swift library GitHub page, but can anyone here explain the problem?

I am working in Xcode Version 13.4.1

Kind regards

Comment: https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift/issues/419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project was running R.swift version 5.4.0.

I had tried to update R.swift to 6.1.0, but had missed the step of importing the R.swift.library into the project instead.
https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift.Library#Installation

Now the R.swift.library is added in the following way in the Package Dependencies.

[how the Package Dependency manager looks after choosing .library instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ILIM.png)

This version of R.swift removed the warnings of XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference & XCSwiftPackageProductDependency.

Hope this helps others as well.